# updating .properties files without a restart?

Tags: keycloak

I updated some properties files (some i18n messages) on a running keycloak. But nothing happens. Do I need to restart keycloak to see the changes? That would be odd, as I instantly see changes to (freemarker) template files.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable theme caching by modifying `standalone.xml` as follows:

```xml
<theme>
<!-- Change the lines:
    <staticMaxAge>2592000</staticMaxAge>
    <cacheThemes>true</cacheThemes>
    <cacheTemplates>true</cacheTemplates>
to: -->
    <staticMaxAge>-1</staticMaxAge>
    <cacheThemes>false</cacheThemes>
    <cacheTemplates>false</cacheTemplates>

    <dir>${jboss.home.dir}/themes</dir>
</theme>
```